# Chrome extension: Inject a script into a single webpage (provided by the user)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension with a single text input field and a button that says "Test banner". My goal is to inject a script that will manipulate the DOM of the given webpage and add a big red banner at the top, but I only want to inject it into the single url that I put in the text field.

Basically my options.html has a text input and a button. When the user enters a URL like google.com I want to open the page and inject into only that instance of the page. My issue is that

```
  $('#start-button').button().click(function() {
    var url = $('#url').value;
    window.open(url)
  });
```

My url successfully opens, but I "wish" I could "open and inject". Since I can't do that I've been relegated to trying to setup a background.js that listens for a window being opened, but that code keeps injecting into every tab with the url that I set (example. If I type google.com, then it will keep injecting into every google.com tab that I open).

So my question is... is there some kind of api available where I can do `window.openAndInject(url)`?

Note: I am very very new to this. Please excuse any noob mistakes I may have made.

Comment: Use chrome.tabs.create + chrome.tabs.executeScript with this tab's id.

Comment: @wOxxOm aha. Okay so the tab that gets created gets a unique id that's "guaranteed" not to be used by any other tab or anything?

Comment: Also, if you post it as the answer I can mark it as correct. I got it working. Still want to do some testing to see if there's any way that this can get messed up, but I think this gets the job done perfectly.